# Using Google App Engine with mobile apps and a web app

Tags: google-app-engine

I have just started looking into using Google App Engine for a project I'm developing. The project will have an Android and iPhone app as well as a web application that a set of users can log into. I have a couple basic questions concerning the use of Google App Engine...

1. Is it possible to use google app engine in conjunction with your own web app? Or would I post the web app itself on Google App Engine? Is it that I'd use my web app AND Google App Engine, or would those be the same thing? I guess this is the main point I'm not clear on.
2. I'm kind of concerned about putting all of our data on Google's servers and not directly owned by myself. Is this just something I'll have to get over?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: The web app will need to have a decent amount of functionality in addition to the mobile apps. Is the Google App Engine mostly for projects which only/mainly have mobile apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine includes [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) for Android, iOS and web clients.  The client web app can be hosted on AppEngine or elsewhere.  If you host the client web app in the same application that hosts the Cloud Endpoints, authentication and data sharing is easier to achieve.

Yes, you'll just have to get over putting all of your data on Google's servers.  Google does not publish or index your data, except for the data your app itself publishes to anonymous clients.